# Manually editing 5010 837 P / 837 I EDI File

Tags: edi, x12

I am working on Manually editing 5010 837 P / 837 I file using ICD 10 Diagnosis Code.

Using an existing file which has 4010 Diagnosis Codes, I am manually editing this for Testing Purpose.

I couldn't understand SE Transaction Set Trailer as well as GE ..

In the below syntax, Can i assume that SE*106*000000010 as 10th Claim?

```
SE*106*000000010~
GE*10*11~IEA*1*000000011~
```

I am working on creating only one claim file. Whether SE and GE are important?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with programming?

Comment: This is part of programming. EDI file has its own Syntax. I should have mentioned as EDI Programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SE, GE and IEA are ALL important.  They are the "closing" part of the EDI interchange envelope that correspond to the ST, GS, and ISA.

You cannot have a valid X12 EDI document without these envelopes (with few exceptions).  The ISA is the interchange envelope and is ended by the IEA.  The GS is the Group Envelope which is ended by the GE.  The ST is the Transaction (or document) envelope which is ended by the SE.

The control numbers in the envelopes have to match.  This was basically built into the standard from the beginning to help combat unreliable communication protocols.  It also helps the translators understand where each part of the interchange ends (you can have multiple transactions and groups per interchange).

The SE01 is the number of included segments.  The SE02 is the Control number that needs to match ST02.

The GE01 is the number of transactions. The GE02 is the control number that needs to match the GS06.

The IEA01 is the number of groups.  The IEA02 is the control number that needs to match  ISA13.

Download EDI Notepad from Liaison to help you figure this stuff out.

Comment: Thank you Andrew !! Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0):

EDIs are divided into interchanges, and each further comprises of groups and groups into segments.
SE*106*000000010 means its probably the 10th segment (although it's just a unique number).

If your question is regarding Business prospective. I would suggest to make sure that every ST-SE contains only one claim(this can be made sure by matching the CLM* and SE*837* count in your EDI file)

Comment: I wrote that project in September 2015 :) 5 years ago !!